# Поиск в файле по двум параметрам

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Необходимо спарсить из файла цифры и занести их в гуглотаблицу. На данный момент получается такой вариант:

```
var start, end, name;
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    start = response.indexOf('<td class="value last-child">  ', end) + 31;
    start = response.indexOf('            ', start) + 12;
    end = response.indexOf(' <abbr>', start);
    name = response.substring(start, end);

  cell.setValue(name);
  cell = cell.offset(0,4);
  }
```

Он из этого кода:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="info">
    <td class="club">
      <b><a href="/ru/clubs/390">ТЕКСТ1</a></b>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="result merge">
      <td class="value last-child">  
        1309.17 <abbr></abbr>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
  <tr class="info">
    <td class="club">
      <b><a href="/ru/clubs/391">ТЕКСТ2</a></b>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="result merge">
      <td class="value last-child">  
        1200.15 <abbr></abbr>
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

выдергивает значения "1309.17" и "1200.15" и вставляет в таблицу. 
Как мне сделать поиск так, чтобы он искал сначала текст `"/ru/clubs/391"`, а потом уже в блоке `<tbody></tbody>` с этим текстом данные в виде цифр `1200.15`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял ваш вопрос, но попробую ответить.

href для ссылки  это атрибут.

Ищите по атрибуту, например так

```
var el = $("a[href=/ru/clubs/391]"); // Так вы найдете ссылку
```

Теперь найдите родителя для этой ссылки, то есть вы как бы двигаетесь от этого элемента вверх по иерархии и найдете родителя.

```
el = $(el).parents("tbody");
```

Теперь ищите внутри этого элемента (родителя)

```
$(el).find("tr.result.merge td.value.last-child").text();
```

**Ну или в одну строку:**

```
$("a[href=/ru/clubs/391]").parents("tbody").find("tr.result.merge td.value.last-child").text();
```

Так вы получите текст, который народится в одной иерархии (у которого общий родитель) с каким-то другим элементом, не обязательно соседним.

*Обратите внимание, что я использовал библиотеку jQuery*